# Can't get json from unsplash api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app

I was trying to make a image search app with unsplash api. I can access api by writing the url in to the browser like this [this](https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=1424074b20f17701ec8c0601fd15ca686c70e2cb0e645f8137533d8063e664bc&query=woods) but I can't get it to work within my code. anyone can help? Also no error is occurring and I am trying to get the json file to be printed to the console. I am following this documentation [here](https://unsplash.com/documentation).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

      this.state = {
        applicationId: '1424074b20f17701ec8c0601fd15ca686c70e2cb0e645f8137533d8063e664bc',
        url: 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=',
        pagecount: 1
      }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    let query = document.getElementById('input').value;
    fetch(this.state.url + this.state.applicationId + '&query=' + query + '&page=' + this.state.pagecount)
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('error occured' + err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form id='form'>
          <input type='text' id='input' ></input>
          <input type='submit' id='submit' onClick={this.handleClick} ></input>
        </form>
        <div id='field' >
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**: You Fetch does not return actual JSON, it return just HTTP response. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the json() method.

Have you checked your final `URL`? I got a result just with few changes. Are you getting client_id and query word?

**Solution**

```js
const client_id ="1424074b20f17701ec8c0601fd15ca686c70e2cb0e645f8137533d8063e664bc"
const query = 'woods';
function makeCall(){

  fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=${client_id}&query=${query}`,{method:'get'}).
then(res=>res.json())
.then(res=>console.log("boommer",res))
.catch(res=>console.log("error",res))

}
makeCall();
```

Working example of react [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3xkjm1623)